# How to change/remove/ignore a http header just before parsing the response in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discogs-api

I'm currently working with Node to get data from an API (Discogs API) and I've got this error when requesting :

```
{ [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }
```

Using this link : http://api.discogs.com/releases/249504 (but I have the same error for every other requests when `content-length != actual content length`)

And this code :

```
var http  = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.discogs.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/releases/249504',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

I found that the Content-length value is always smaller than the real response byte length.

```
Content-length : 2142

Actual Byte Length : 7,734 Bytes (according to https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)
```

I've read that Node's Parser is really strict and that's why it fails parsing the response.

Finally, I'm asking you if there is a way to either ignore/modify/delete a Header just before Node parses the response, so the parser can do his work by ignoring the Content-Length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to a (perceived, see below) invalid content-length, because it also doesn't work using cURL:

```
$ curl  http://api.discogs.com/releases/249504
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Apparently the API server requires that a user agent header is set:

```
var options = {
  hostname : 'api.discogs.com',
  port     : 80,
  path     : '/releases/249504',
  method   : 'GET',
  headers  : { 'user-agent' : 'foo/1.0' }
};
```

As for the difference in content-length: 2142 is the size of a gzip-compressed response (`content-encoding: gzip`), 7734 is the size of an uncompressed response. Apparently, your byte-counter test requests uncompressed responses only but the client that you checked the header with is requesting a compressed response.

Comment: Thanks to your simple answer I now undestand why it worked in my browser (because it sends an user-agent).
And also why the length was not the same (before/after compression)

Answer (score 1):

Moving back to the topic of **changing headers just before parsing the response in Node**, you can do it easily by replacing of standard handler with your own function on `socket: "data"` event.

https://github.com/nodejs/http2/blob/master/lib/_http_client.js#L655

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers); // without "Pragma: public" header

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });
});

// catch socket object on conection initialization
req.on('socket', function (socket) {
    // https://nodejs.org/api/events.html
    var standardHandler = socket.listeners('data')[0];
    socket.off('data', standardHandler);

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        var str = data.toString();
        console.log(str);
        // HTTP/1.x 200 OK
        // Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 04:36:25 GMT
        // Connection: close
        // Pragma: public
        // Expires: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 05:36:25 GMT
        // Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
        // Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
        // Content-Length: 533424
        // Content-Encoding: gzip
        // Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, User-Agent
        //  
        // <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD

        // Do anything you need
        // removing 4 line
        var lines = str.split('\r\n');
        lines.splice(3, 1)
        str = lines.join('\r\n');

        // Now pass new data onto standard request handler
        standardHandler.call(socket, Buffer.from(str, "utf-8"));
    })
});

req.end();
```